# How to set own app as default

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, default, android-contacts

I have created an phone book app now I want to set it as a default phone book anyone please tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set [APP_CONTACTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_CONTACTS) category on your main activity

Comment: i am doing but this is not working <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_CONTACTS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: And if there were two apps that have these lines, which one get default?!